# Struts JQuery Tree Assigning Node Specific url using jsone Data

Tags: json, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I tried the same code as on http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/TreeTag

It's working fine to generate the tree structure, but I want to assign different URLs to each `TreeNode` of the tree. How can I do same with JSON response?

A Tree Component with a JSON Data Source.
JSP Code

```
    <s:url var="treeDataUrl" action="json-tree-data"/>
    <sjt:tree 
            id="jsonTree" 
            href="%{treeDataUrl}"
            onClickTopics="treeClicked" 
    />
```

Java Action Code

```
@ParentPackage(value = "showcase")
public class JsonTreeData extends ActionSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2886756982077980790L;
    private List<TreeNode> nodes = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
    private String id = "";

    @Actions( { @Action(value = "/json-tree-data", results = { @Result(name = "success", type = "json", params = {
                    "root", "nodes" }) }) })
    public String execute() {

            TreeNode nodeA = new TreeNode();
            nodeA.setId("A" + id);
            nodeA.setTitle("Node A" + id);
            nodeA.setState(TreeNode.NODE_STATE_CLOSED);

            TreeNode nodeB = new TreeNode();
            nodeB.setId("B" + id);
            nodeB.setState(TreeNode.NODE_STATE_CLOSED);
            nodeB.setTitle("Node B" + id);

            TreeNode nodeC = new TreeNode();
            nodeC.setId("C" + id);
            nodeC.setState(TreeNode.NODE_STATE_CLOSED);
            nodeC.setTitle("Node C" + id);

            nodes.add(nodeA);
            nodes.add(nodeB);
            nodes.add(nodeC);

            return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getJSON() {
            return execute();
    }

    public List<TreeNode> getNodes() {
            return nodes;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
    }
}
```

TreeNode.java

```
    public class TreeNode implements Serializable {

    public static final String NODE_STATE_CLOSED = "closed";
    public static final String NODE_STATE_OPEN = "open";

    private Map<String, Object> attr;

    private Collection<TreeNode> children;
    private String icon;
    private String id;
    private String state = TreeNode.NODE_STATE_CLOSED;
    private String title;

    public TreeNode() {
            super();
    }

    public TreeNode(String title) {
            super();
            this.title = title;
    }

    public TreeNode(String id, String title) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
    }

    public TreeNode(String title, Collection<TreeNode> children) {
            super();
            this.title = title;
            this.children = children;
    }

    public TreeNode(String id, String title, Collection<TreeNode> children) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.children = children;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAttr() {
            return attr;
    }

    public Collection<TreeNode> getChildren() {
            return children;
    }

    /**
     * Get the Tree Node Title
     */
    public String getData() {
            return title;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
            return icon;
    }

    public String getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public String getState() {
            return state;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
            return title;
    }

    public void setAttr(Map<String, Object> attr) {
            this.attr = attr;
    }

    /**
     * Set the Tree Node Childrens
     *
     * @param children
     */
    public void setChildren(Collection<TreeNode> children) {
            this.children = children;
    }

    /**
     * Set the Tree Node Icon
     *
     * @param icon
     */
    public void setIcon(String icon) {
            this.icon = icon;
    }

    /**
     * Set the Tree Node Id
     *
     * @param icon
     */
    public void setId(String id) {

            this.id = id;
            if (this.attr == null) {
                    attr = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            }

            if (this.attr.containsKey("id")) {
                    this.attr.remove("id");
            }
            this.attr.put("id", id);
     }

    /**
     * Set the Tree Node State open or closed
     *
     * @param state
     */
    public void setState(String state) {
            this.state = state;
    }

    /**
     * Set the Tree Node Title
     *
     * @param title
     */
    public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append("TreeNode [id=").append(id).append(", title=").append(
                            title).append(", icon=").append(icon).append(", state=")
                            .append(state).append(", attr=").append(attr).append(
                                            ", children=").append(children).append("]");
            return builder.toString();
    }


    }
```

For Each Node It generates output as

```
<li id="C0" class="jstree-closed jstree-last">
    <ins class="jstree-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e">&nbsp;</ins>
    <a href="#" class="ui-state-default">
                 <ins class="jstree-icon ui-icon ui-icon-folder-collapsed">&nbsp;</ins>
        Node C0
    </a>
</li>
```

I want to assign each node specific url to corresponding anchor tag generated as above.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where do you want to assign it? Is it assignable or if you assign it it doesn't work?

Comment: I want to assign it to anchor tag generated for each node OR
I just want to hit the node specific url when i click on node.

I tried it to set it by adding String href in TreeNode.java but it doesn't work.

I tried by adding {href:"url"} in attr map in treeNode but it assignes parameter to li tag instead of anchor tag in output